# An old animated movie about a boy on a spaceship searching for treasure

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember the name of an old animated movie. Description will be a bit vague but here goes:

It's a cross between *Treasure Planet* and *Sword in the Stone*. (it's not *Star Chaser*). It's a family animated movie about a blonde boy. He finds a sword with an invisible blade, the blade materializes when he uses it. He is on board a talking spaceship - the spaceship has a little rectangular head that pops out when he talks to the boy.

At one point the boy asks the ship to do something and strikes the console. I think he was searching for a treasure or something. The movie is not set in space exclusively, they travel around on a planet. I don't remember other characters.

I don't remember the period - 80's possibly very early 90's

Sorry, I know its vague but that's all I can remember and I'm desperately trying to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you said not *[Starchaser: The Legend of Orin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starchaser:_The_Legend_of_Orin)*, but are you sure? It features a sword with an invisible blade, it came out in 1985, and it has him going from living on a planet to searching for the sword's blade.

> The twist is that, after losing the hilt, he learns that the sword never really had any power. The "invisible blade" was something that he was generating.

The starship that they travel on is controlled by a computer named Arthur who apparently extrudes a head like this:

[image: Image of Arthur extruding a "head" on a stalk]

Film's Poster:

[image: Film poster for Starchaser: The Legend of Orin]

### Trailer

Comment: You may well be right Sean, I was almost sure it WASN'T Star Chaser but I'll check it out and let you know. The AI head (Arthur) got me thinking! I'll revert back to let you know.Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Sean, strangely enough I did come across the trailer during my search but still didn't put two and two together. Arthur was the defining clue - good job and thanks again.